# Telegram API sendPhoto gives back "Bad Request: type of file mismatch"

Tags: python, image, bots, telegram, telepot

I'm trying to upload a photo using telepot python library in a telegram bot.

```
fd, path = tempfile.mkstemp()

image_bytes = requests.get(url=fileUrl, stream=True)
with open(path, 'wb') as strm:
   for chunk in image_bytes:
      strm.write(chunk)

photoFile = open(path, mode='rb') 
fileId = bot.sendPhoto(chat_id='chat_id', photo=photoFile)
```

This code gives me this error:

```
telepot.exception.TelegramError: ('Bad Request: type of file mismatch', 400, {'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': 'Bad Request: type of file mismatch'})
```

If I try to access to the local file created by tempfile.mkstemp(), it exists and gives the correct image. 
I also tried specifying the extension of the image in the image name but there is still the same error.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before, but in other prerequisites. I tried to specify fileId when sending the video, but that fileId was recognised as Document, rather than Video. I re-uploaded file as video, specified new fileId and it worked.